# Show specific no results message if no results found

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-lists, message, show

Here's my code below, which works like this: 
If somebody checks a checkbox (or multiple checkboxes) the code filters and only shows the correct results from an unordered list.

What I would like to do: If there are no results it should show a specific no results found message, for example: "Oops, no results found".

Could you help me with this? Thank you for your help in advance.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.filtered li').hide();
$("[name='filter']").change(function() {
$('.filtered li').show();

   $("[name='filter']:checked").each( function() {

   var  tag=$(this).val();

   $('.filtered li')
            .children(".tags:not(:contains('"+tag+"'))")
            .parent()
            .hide();

    });

});
});
```

The HTML part:

```
  <input id="filter1" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter1>filter1
        <input id="filter2" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter2>filter2
        <input id="filter3" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter3>filter3</br>


        <input id="filter4" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter4>filter4
        <input id="filter5" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter5>filter5
        <input id="filter6" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter6>filter6
        <input id="filter7" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter7>filter7
        <input id="filter8" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter8>filter8
        <input id="filter9" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter9>filter9</br>


        <input id="filter10" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter10>filter10
        <input id="filter11" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter11>filter11
        <input id="filter12" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter12>filter12</br>


        <input id="filter13" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter13>filter13
        <input id="filter14" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter14>filter14
        <input id="filter15" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter15>filter15
        <input id="filter16" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter16>filter16
        <input id="filter17" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter17>filter17</br>


        <input id="filter18" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter18>filter18
        <input id="filter19" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter19>filter19
        <input id="filter20" name="filter" size="40"/ type='checkbox' value=filter20>filter20</br>

<br><br>
<div id="HELP" class="filtered">

<ul>
    <li>1
        <span class="tags">filter1 filter5 filter7 filter9</span>      
    </li>

    <li>2
        <span class="tags">filter2 filter15 filter17 filter19</span>      
    </li>
    <li>3
        <span class="tags">filter4 filter5 filter13 filter12</span>      
    </li>
    <li>4
        <span class="tags">filter7 filter14 filter18 filter19</span>      
    </li>
    <li>5
        <span class="tags">filter9 filter11 filter14 filter20</span>      
    </li>
    <li>6
        <span class="tags">filter20 filter10 filter16 filter8</span>      
    </li>
    <li>7
        <span class="tags">filter5 filter7 filter12 filter17</span>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
var results = $('.filtered li').children(".tags:not(:contains('"+tag+"'))").length;
if(results < 1){
   // show some no results message
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan yeah i meant .length (sorry been working in php all day)

Comment: @richard is this correct if so can you mark it as such please?